# Is calculating a height of UITableViewCell changed on iOS 8?

Tags: ios, ios8

As you know, in iOS 7 and prior version, `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is called before `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. In other words, if UITableView doesn't use estimated height  feature, it calculates height of each cells before making cells.

However, I recently found that the delegate method who calculates a height of a cell was called by `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` every single making cell. I wonder why the calling process is changed in iOS8. In addition, I would like to know proper way to set up UITableView supporting dynamic height of a cell in iOS8 and to keep the former way which is used in prior versions.

Comment: You mean `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath` is not called anymore in iOS8?

Comment: @mostruash Nope. `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called by `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't implement the delegate method: `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` then `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` will be called for every cell in the tableview.

Your question doesn't show that you are implementing this method, so it is likely that this is the problem.

Comment: tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath method is called for every cell in-spite of tableView:estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection method which is called for header section and not for cell.

Comment: Which is not what I've said.

Answer (score 0):

iOS8 supports dynamic cell sizes. If you do not implement `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`, and have auto layout enabled on your cell, the system will calculate a size that fits the cell's content and give that size to the cell. This is very convenient, because starting with iOS8, implementing dynamic cell sizes is now very easy, whereas it was very difficult before.